# Workaround for POP3 and catchall mailbox multiple emails issue

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, pop3

I previously had an issue where emails sent to multiple users would appear multiple times per user (see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/434376/emails-to-multiple-recipients-get-delivered-multiple-times-per-user)).

I have discovered the source of the issue lies in the fact that multiple emails (one intended for each user) are pulled in by the `POP3` connector and into the `catchall` mailbox, and then the email headers are getting each email sent to each one of the recipients (probably makes more sense in the original thread).

What I could do with is a workaround for this issue while we investigate either a move to per user `POP3` connections, or hopefully a move to `SMTP`. Is there an improved `POP3` connector I can use with Exchange 2003, or a better way of having it all set up that would avoid this issue?

Comment: Why not just use the IMAP connector instead? Offers more functionality and works much the same as the POP connector.  Most phones now support it as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are other POP3 connectors out there that automatically filter out these duplicates. POPcon (http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm) would be one that keeps a database of already forwarded emails and recipients. It checks the Message-ID of each incoming email and only forwards the email to that recipient if that specific recipient didn't already get that specific message. 
Somehow the Microsoft connector is missing this feature, so other than using a different connector your only options are moving to SMTP or moving to individual POP3 mailboxes for each user.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but we've started again from scratch. Their server was a complete mess of workarounds and was pretty much impractical to repair (an insurance write-off if you will)